# Digital Diversity

Tags: code-golf, sequence, number-theory, base-conversion

A positive integer may be represented in an integer base \$1 \le b < \infty\$.

When converted to that base it has some number of distinct digits.

Any positive integer in base \$1\$ has \$1\$ distinct digit.

Most positive integers in base \$2\$ have \$2\$ distinct digits, the exceptions being those of the form \$2^n - 1\$, which only have \$1\$.

So the first positive integer that may be represented in an integer base with \$1\$ unique digit is \$1\$ and the first that may be represented with \$2\$ distinct digits is \$2\$.

We can say that \$1\$ is the first integer with digital diversity \$1\$ and \$2\$ is the first integer with digital diversity \$2\$.

#### Challenge:

Given a positive integer \$n\$ return the first positive integer (in base ten*) that has a digital diversity of \$n\$.

* if your language only supports a specific base (e.g. unary or binary) then you may output in that base.

Your algorithm must *work in theory* for any positive integer input: it *may* fail because the precision of your language's integer is too small for the output; but *may not* fail because base conversion is only defined up to some limit.

#### Test cases

```
input  output
   1     1
   2     2
   3     11
   4     75
   5     694
   6     8345
   7     123717
  17     49030176097150555672
  20     5271200265927977839335179
  35     31553934355853606735562426636407089783813301667210139
  63     3625251781415299613726919161860178255907794200133329465833974783321623703779312895623049180230543882191649073441
 257     87678437238928144977867204156371666030574491195943247606217411725999221158137320290311206746021269051905957869964398955543865645836750532964676103309118517901711628268617642190891105089936701834562621017362909185346834491214407969530898724148629372941508591337423558645926764610261822387781382563338079572769909101879401794746607730261119588219922573912353523976018472514396317057486257150092160745928604277707892487794747938484196105308022626085969393774316283689089561353458798878282422725100360693093282006215082783023264045094700028196975508236300153490495688610733745982183150355962887110565055971546946484175232
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest solution in bytes wins.

[**OEIS: A049363**](http://oeis.org/A049363) - also smallest pandigital number in base n.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṖaWḅ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmWYVfhuIU&input=) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmWYVfhuIUKxbzDh-KCrEc&input=&args=MSwgMiwgMywgNCwgNSwgNiwgNywgMTcsIDIwLCAyNSwgNjMsIDI1Nw)

#### How it works

```
ṖaWḅ  Main link. Argument: n

Ṗ     Pop; yield [1, 2, 3, ..., n-1].
  W   Wrap; yield [n].
 a    Logical AND; yield [n, 2, 3, ..., n-1].
   ḅ  Convert the result from base n to integer.
```

Comment: I forgot place values could overflow, beats my lousy 7 :)

Comment: I wish there was a rep vs bytes used chart per user on codegolf. Maybe a plot of total bytes used vs current rep.

Comment: Took me a bit to figure out why this works ... slickly done!

Answer (score 9):

## Python, 40 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=1:n*(n<k+2)or-~f(n,k+1)*n-k
```

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/c1Y66V).

#### How it works

A number with **n** distinct digits must clearly be expressed in base **b ≥ n**. Since our goal is to minimize the number, **b** should also be as small as possible, so **b = n** is the logical choice.

That leaves us with arranging the digits **0, …, n-1** to create a number as small as possible, which means the most significant digits must be kept as small as possible. Since the first digit cannot be a **0** in the canonical representation, the smallest number is
**(1)(0)(2)...(n-2)(n-1)<sub>n</sub> = n<sup>n-1</sup> + 2n<sup>n-3</sup> + … + (n-2)n + (n-1)**, which **f** computes recursively.

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, <s>54</s> 46 bytes

This is a very *very* ***very**!* fast, iterative solution.

```python
n=r=input();k=2
while k<n:r=r*n+k;k+=1
print r
```

[**Try it online**](https://repl.it/Dwfr)

There's no recursion, so it works for large input. Here's the result of `n = 17000` (takes 1-2 seconds):

http://pastebin.com/UZjgvUSW

Comment: How long did input 17000 take? It takes 26 seconds on my machine, which seems slow compared to Jelly's 0.9 seconds...

Comment: Similar but other way around for three bytes less: `lambda n:n**~-n+sum(i*n**(n+~i)for i in range(2,n))`

Comment: 46 bytes and *a lot* faster: `n=r=input();k=2\nwhile k<n:r=r*n+k;k+=1\nprint r`

Comment: Yes, it's amazing how much faster while loops are than comprehensions in Python.

Comment: @JonathanAllan That's not the reason. Computing the powers is *very* slow, while the loop only uses multiplication and addition.

Comment: @Dennis Ah, I didn't spot that, but `while` is much faster (especially if one uses a variable in place of an `enumerate()`)

Comment: @Dennis It took about 30-32 seconds.

Comment: You can simplify a bit by shifting the index: `lambda n:n**~-n+sum(n**i*(n+~i)for i in range(n-2))`

Comment: @xnor That's basically what Jonathan Allan said above (kind of).

Comment: FYI - takes just over 1/2 second on my laptop (i7-3610QM@2.3GHZ)

Comment: With PyPy, I get 150 ms on my laptop.

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), 29 bytes

```
f=(b,n=b)=>n>2?f(b,--n)*b+n:b
```

Answer (score 5):

## J, 9 bytes

```
#.],2}.i.
```

Based on @Dennis' [method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96231/6710).

### Usage

```
   f =: #.],2}.i.
   (,.f"0) >: i. 7
1      1
2      2
3     11
4     75
5    694
6   8345
7 123717
   f 17x
49030176097150555672
```

### Explanation

```
#.],2}.i.  Input: n
       i.  Get range, [0, 1, ..., n-1]
    2}.    Drop the first 2 values, [2, 3, ...., n-1]
  ]        Get n
   ,       Prepend it, [n, 2, 3, ..., n-1]
#.         Convert that to decimal from a list of base-n digits and return
```

There is an alternative solution based on using the permutation index. Given input *n*, create the list of digits `[0, 1, ..., n]`, and find the permutation using an index of *n*!, and convert that as a list of base-*n* digits. The corresponding solution in J for **12 bytes**

```
#.]{.!A.i.,]  Input: n
        i.    Make range [0, 1, ..., n-1]
           ]  Get n
          ,   Join, makes [0, 1, ..., n-1, n]
     !        Factorial of n
      A.      Permutation index using n! into [0, 1, ..., n]
  ]           Get n
   {.         Take the first n values of that permutation
              (This is to handle the case when n = 1)
#.            Convert that to decimal from a list of base-n digits and return
```

Comment: Could it be shorter to construct `[1,0,2,3,...,n-1]`?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I can't find a way, but I did notice that the permutation indices of those would be (*n*-1)!

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, <s>37</s> <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```
->n{s=n;(2...n).map{|d|s=s*n+d};s}
```

The answer for a given `n` takes the form `10234...(n-1)` in base `n`. Using `n=10` as an example:

Start with `n`: `10`

Multiply by `n` and add 2: `102`

Mutliply by `n` and add 3: `1023`

And so on.

EDIT: Shorter to use map, it seems.

EDIT 2: Thanks for the tip, m-chrzan!

Comment: `(2...n)` will be a byte shorter.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 31 bytes

```haskell
f n=foldl((+).(*n))n[2..n-1]
```

Converts the list `[n,2,3,...,n-1]` to base `n` using Horner's method via folding. A less golfed version of this is given [on the OEIS page](http://oeis.org/A049363).

Thanks to nimi for 3 bytes!

Comment: I don't know Haskell too well, does the fold require the function to be named (`f`?) to be a valid a golf solution? (it's just `f` is not referenced later in the code)

Comment: @JonathanAllan The lambda function form in Haskell is `\n->fold1...`, which is just as long as naming it. You can write a point-free function where the input variable isn't named by combining sub-functions, but that would be awful here with three references to `n`.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the explanation. Haskell syntax confuses me somewhat.

Comment: You can use `foldl` and start with `n`: `f n=foldl((+).(*n))n[2..n-1]`

Answer (score 3):

### [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 9 bytes

```
ri__,2>+b
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cmlfXywyPiti&input=MTc)

#### Explanation

```
ri   e# Read input N.
__   e# Make two copies.
,    e# Turn last copy into range [0 1 2 ... N-1].
2>   e# Discard up to two leading values.
+    e# Prepend a copy of N.
b    e# Treat as base-N digits.
```

Answer (score 3):

### CJam (9 bytes)

```
qi_,X2$tb
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qi_%2CX2%24tb&input=17)

#### Dissection

Obviously the smallest number with digital diversity `n` is found by base-converting  `[1 0 2 3 ... n-1]` in base `n`. However, note that the base conversion built-in doesn't require the digits to be in the range `0 .. n-1`.

```
qi    e# Read integer from stdin
_,    e# Duplicate and built array [0 1 ... n-1]
X2$t  e# Set value at index 1 to n
b     e# Base conversion
```

Note that in the special case `n = 1` we get `1 [0] 1 1 tb` giving `1 [0 1] b` which is `1`.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
DL¦¨v¹*y+
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=REzCpsKodsK5Knkr&input=MjU3)

**Explanation**

`n = 4` used for example.

```
D           # duplicate input
            # STACK: 4, 4
 L          # range(1, a)
            # STACK: 4, [1,2,3,4]
  ¦¨        # remove first and last element of list
            # STACK: 4, [2,3]
    v       # for each y in list
     ¹*     # multiply current stack with input
       y+   # and add y
            # STACK, first pass: 4*4+2 = 18
            # STACK, second pass: 18*4+3 = 75
```

Answer (score 2):

## C++ -  <strike>181</strike>  55

Was about to post that real cool solution using `<numeric>`:

```
#import <vector>
#import <numeric>
using namespace std;int f(int n){vector<int> v(n+1);iota(v.begin(),v.end(),0);swap(v[0],v[1]);return accumulate(v.begin(),v.end()-1,0,[n](int r,int a){return r*n+a;});}
```

and then i realized it is **way** easier:

```
int g(int n){int r=n,j=2;for(;j<n;)r=r*n+j++;return r;}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>34 31</s>  30 bytes

Translated from the Haskell example on [the OEIS page](https://oeis.org/A049363).

```perl6
{(1,0,|(2..^$^n)).reduce: $n×*+*}        # 34
{(1,0,|(2..^$^n)).reduce: $n* *+*}       # 34

{reduce $^n×*+*,1,0,|(2..^$n)}           # 31
{[[&($^n×*+*)]] 1,0,|(2..^$n)}           # 31

{reduce $_×*+*,1,0,|(2..^$_)}            # 30
```

- `[&(…)]` turns `…` into an in-place infix operator
- The `[…]` shown above turns an infix op into a fold (left or right depending on the operator associativity)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{
  reduce

    # declare the blocks only parameter ｢$n｣ ( the ｢^｣ twigil )
    # declare a WhateverCode lambda that takes two args ｢*｣
    $^n × * + *

    # a list that always contains at least (1,0)
    1, 0,
    # with a range slipped in
    |(
      2 ..^ $n # range from 2 up-to and excluding ｢$n｣
               # it is empty if $n <= 2
    )
}
```

### Usage:

```perl6
my &code = {reduce $_×*+*,1,0,|(2..^$_)}

say code 1; # 1
say code 2; # 2
say code 3; # 11
say code 4; # 75
say code 7; # 123717

# let's see how long it takes to calculate a largish value:

my $start-time = now;
$_ = code 17000;
my $calc-time = now;
$_ = ~$_; # 25189207981120412047...86380901260421982999
my $display-time = now;

say "It takes only { $calc-time - $start-time } seconds to calculate 17000";
say "but { $display-time - $calc-time } seconds to stringify"

# It takes only 1.06527824 seconds to calculate 17000
# but 5.3929017 seconds to stringify
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>84</s> 76 bytes

*Thanks to [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard) for golfing 8 bytes*

```
(({})<>){(({}[()]))}{}(<{}{}>)((())){{}({<({}[()])><>({})<>}{}{})([][()])}{}
```

[Try it online!](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=KCh7fSk8Pil7KCh7fVsoKV0pKX17fSg8e317fT4pKCgoKSkpe3t9KHs8KHt9WygpXSk-PD4oe30pPD59e317fSkoW11bKCldKX17fQ)

### Explanation

The program pushes the values from `0` to `n-1` to the stack replaces the top `0` and `1` with `1` and `0`. Then it multiplies the top of the stack by `n` and adds the value below it until there is only one value remaining on the stack.

Essentially it finds the digits for the smallest number in base `n` that contains `n` different digits (for `n` > 1 it's always of the form `1023...(n-1)`). It then calculates the number given the digits and the base.

#### Annotated Code

```
(({})<>)       # Pushes a copy of n to the right stack and switches to right stack
{(({}[()]))}{} # While the top of the stack != 0 copy the top of the stack-1
               #   and push it
(<{}{}>)       # Discard the top two values (0 and 1 for n > 1) and push 0
((()))         # Push 1 twice (second time so that the loop is works properly)
{{}            # Loop while stack height > 1
  (            #   Push...
    {<({}[()])><>({})<>}{} # The top value of the stack * n
    {}         #     Plus the value below the top of the stack
  )            #   End push
([][()])}{}    # End loop
```

Comment: You can replace `{}{}(()(<()>))([][()])` with `(<{}{}>)([(())][])` to save four bytes

Comment: You could then replace that with `(<{}{}>)((()))` to save four more bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
o1 hU ìU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=bzEgaFUg7FU&input=Nw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 79 bytes

```
listen to N
cast N
X's1
let T be N
while N-X-1
let X be+1
let T be T*N+X

say T
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Comment: [Mystery Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zz2KH8vAjsI&ab_channel=PaponeMusic-CopyrightFreeMusic)

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 26 bytes

```julia
\(n,k=n)=k<3?n:n\~-k*n+~-k
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=XChuLGs9bik9azwzP246blx-LWsqbit-LWsKCmZvciBuIGluIGJpZyhbMTo3OyBbMTcsIDIwLCAzNSwgNjMsIDI1N11dKQogICAgQHByaW50ZigiJXVcbiV1XG5cbiIsIG4sIFwobikpCmVuZA&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## [ShapeScript](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/shapescript), 25 bytes

```
_0?1'1+@2?*1?+@'2?2-*!#@#
```

Input is in unary, output is in decimal. [Try it online!](http://shapescript.tryitonline.net/#code=XzA_MScxK0AyPyoxPytAJzI_Mi0qISNAIw&input=MTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTE)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 78 Bytes

```
for(;$i<$a=$argn;)$s=bcadd($s,bcmul($i<2?1-$i:$i,bcpow($a,$a-1-$i++)));echo$s;
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d753331f5d752c706587d73459ae4b9b5606a377)

60 Bytes works only till n=16 with the precision in the testcases

For n=144 INF

n=145 NAN

```
for(;$j<$a=$argn;)$t+=($j<2?1-$j:$j)*$a**($a-1-$j++);echo$t;
```

Answer (score 1):

## k, 12 bytes

Based off of [Dennis' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96231/42775).

```
{x/x,2+!x-2}
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 39 bytes

Does not use `=>`

```
function f(b,n){throw f(b,n>2?--n:1)*b}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
B¹ṙ_1tḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3@nQzoc7Z8Ybljzcsfj///@mAA)